How to get the number of rows written by CSVPrinter?
My code runs a SELECTstatement, and saves the entire ResultSet into a file with a single call to CSVprinter.printRecords(resultSet).
This works very nicely except, I'd like to know, how many records were written... The method itself does not return anything -- an opportunity to make life easier missed by the developers.
I tried calling resultSet.getRow() after printing -- hoping, it will be at the last one, thus giving me the total -- but that always returns zero.
I tried calling resultSet.last() before getRow(), but that fails, because mine is a "forward only" result-set. The afterLast() fails for the same reason.
I could loop over the result-set myself -- passing individual rows to CSVPrinter and counting them -- but that certainly is not as convenient and concise. Is there any other way?
Update: created the improvement request, for whatever that's worth...

You can also do it with a Proxy:
    public class CountingResultSet implements InvocationHandler {
        private ResultSet original; 
        private int counter;

    public static ResultSet newProxy(final ResultSet original) {
        return (ResultSet) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                OracleVArrayTests.class.getClassLoader(), 
                  new Class[] { ResultSet.class }, 
                  new CountingResultSet(original)); 
    }
    
    public CountingResultSet(final ResultSet original) {
        this.original = original ;
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
      throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("next")) {
            Boolean res = (Boolean)method.invoke(this.original, args);
            if (res) ++this.counter;
            return res;
        }
        
        return method.invoke(this.original,  args);
    }
    
    int getCounter() { return this.counter; }
}

And getting the count:
    try (final ResultSet rs = CountingResultSet.newProxy((ResultSet) ...)) {
    ...
    ((CountingResultSet)Proxy.getInvocationHandler(rs)).getCounter();
    ...
    }


Sigh, seems like a lot more coding, than just looping over the rows myself :(

The Proxy solution is shorter…only 30 lines…

The loop is 4 lines...

You can wrap the ResultSet into your own implementation in which you override next() and count the # of calls, that you can later retrieve...

But would the CSVPrinter.printRecords() accept this overloaded implementation?

ResultSet is an interface...

The next version, 1.13.0, adds CSVPrinter.getRecordCount()
This is in git master and snapshot builds for version 1.13.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
